# Limit the element to be stored in List<WebElement> - selenium/java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I need to know how to store the first 10 values in `List<WebElement>` instead of storing all the elements that is present?

Right now my code stores all the elements:

```
By mySelector = By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/ul/li");
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);
for(WebElement e : myElements) {
  System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `position()` with the li.

```
By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/ul/li[position() < 11]")
```